# NaN при увеличении значения счётчика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему выводит `NaN` вместо `3` и т.д.?
В целом это стандартный bootstrap компонет, внутири кнопки добавляются при подгрузке контента по ajax, а эти остаются не тронутыми.

```
<nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"  aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#"  aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Пример кода

```
var page = 1;
$('.pagination li:last-child a').click(function() {
    page = page + 1;
    console.log(page);
    //service_map.load(item, null, page, callback_load_map);
});
```

[image: пример]

По всей видимости на кнопку вешался какой то еще обработчик возможно из bootstrap 
Если так то тоже норм

```
<button id="next">next</button>
$('#next').click(function() {
            page = page + 1;
            console.log(page);

        });
```

Немного плохого кода, и всё работает:

```
var page = 1;
var next = 1;
$('.pagination li:last-child a').click(function() {
    next = next + 1;
    page = next;
    console.log(page);
    //service_map.load(item, null, page, callback_load_map);
});
```

Вот кусок кода где была проблема:

```
var pages = pagination.find('li');
                console.log('page=' + page);
                for (var i = 1; i < pages.length - 1; i++) {
                    if ($(pages[i]).find('a').attr('item_id') == page) {
                        $(pages[i]).addClass('active');
                    }
                    $(pages[i]).find('a').click(function() {
                        page = $(this).attr('item_id');
                        service_map.load(item, null, page, callback_load_map);
                        return false;
                    });
                };
```

Comment: Ошибка не воспроизводится в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wsfL4de/). Скорее всего, ошибка в каком-то другом участке кода.

Comment: Проблема не в этом участке, я так понимаю, вы вырезали проблемный участок перед отправкой сюда. Приведите больше кода и сведений.

Comment: @Regent да не вроде везде норм работает, тут page  глобальная хочу просто кнопкой плюсовать значения, 1-й раз прибавляется а последующие NaN

Comment: @korolariya повторюсь: в приведённом коде проблем нет. То, что "портит" значение `page`, находится где-то в другом коде.

Comment: @korolariya, то, что использует эту переменную дальше ее и портит. В данном куске кода **ошибок нет**.

Comment: @korolariya добавьте в вопрос код, в котором она используется. Надеяться можно только на него.

Comment: Хорошо, давай зайдем по другому, что бы меньше вопросов было и всем стало понятнее. Воспроизведи эту ошибку на jsfiddle, что бы мы смогли ее увидеть. В данный момент попытки это сделать показывают, что все нормально: http://jsfiddle.net/p5e4mx61/

Comment: @AlexKrass там дальше в какм то калбэке стоит page = $(this).attr('item_id');

Comment: @AlexKrass вот на секундочку: `page = $(this).attr('item_id');` ведь совсем не влияет на вопрос, не правда ли? :) Даже вот как-то не смешно...

Comment: Вопрос уже давно пора _закрыть_ до выяснения подробностей. Или я не прав?

Comment: Да уже все понятно стало после page = $(this).attr('item_id'), переменная просто напросто затирается другим значением дальше по коду.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev 2 голоса из 5 уже есть. Но, по-моему, закрывать наполовину оформленный вопрос на первой же минуте неправильно: стоит давать время авторам на исправление. А вот последние минут 5 уже _пора_ закрывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, у тебя выполняются оба обработчика

```
$('.pagination li a').click(...) // Для обычных страниц
$('.pagination li:last-child a').click(...) // Для перехода на следующую
```

Первый обработчик портит значение номера страницы (ставит undefined), после чего инкремент даёт NaN.

Добавь информацию о номере страницы в data-атрибут (число и 2 ключевых слова `prev` и `next`) и работай с ними в одном обработчике. Так будет гораздо удобнее и правильнее.

Comment: Не, после откровения автора про `page = $(this).attr('item_id');` оба ответа не совсем "про то".

Comment: @Regent, вероятно, это и есть тот самый undefined, потому что data-атрибута на последнем элементе списка (судя по отдельному хендлеру) у него нет.

Comment: Я делал так что кнопки по краям не обновляются, в внутри обновляются после прихода контента по ajax, если на них вешать обработчики в калбэке то в итоге получу кучу событий клик на необновляемых кнопках

Comment: В точку не заметил в цикле там где вешаются обработчики на новые кнопки не убрал условием крайние кнопки for (var i = 1; i < pages.length - 1; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что пора кончать использовать глобальные переменные.

```
~function () {
  var page = 1;
  $('.pagination li:last-child a').click(function() {
    page = page + 1;
    console.log(page);
    //service_map.load(item, null, page, callback_load_map);
  });
}();
```

Comment: Можно попытаться и `page++` продвинуть в массы :)

Comment: @Regent, кстати, да. Но в этот код всё равно переписать надо. И кстати, номер страницы, скорее всего, портится обработчиком `$('.pagination li a').click`.

Comment: Судя по комментариям TC, эта переменная используется где-то еще. Так что закрыть ее в замыкании - не вариант (минусую).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в таком случае этот код, который "где-то еще", так же закрывается в совместной области видимости, что бы не засорять глобальную область видимости.

Comment: @AlexKrass в любом случае, на данный момент непонятно, в чём именно ошибка. По идее, из-за этого нет повода ни плюсовать ответ, ни минусовать.

Comment: @AlexKrass, даже если заключить код с ошибкой в замыкание, ошибка не исчезнет. Как следствие -- замыкание не является решением данной проблемы, потому и минус. (Хотя я и согласен, что использовать глобальные переменные так, как это делает ТС нельзя).